# boost:scoped_ptr with legacy C functions that takes char* as input type?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I am new to boost library and started exploring it now at my work for a new project. I want to understand how the scoped_ptr from BOOST works? Till now we are using raw pointers in all our codes and I propsed to use SmartPointers to make the memory management easy. Our programming is not a pure C++ language but its integrated application language. For example we are trying to understand how we can initialize a scoped_ptr to NULL and pass the raw pointer to the application API. Consider the code below

This is the API from the application toolkit which takes arguments like this

```
int SOME_API_FUNC(int obj, const char* prop, char** cValue);
```

I cannot change the API because it is not published.

Now the parameter *cValue* is where we want to use Smart Pointer so that the memory management is automated since the API dynamically allocates some memory for it and assigns a value and returns.

We tried with scoped_ptr declaring it like this

```
boost::scoped_ptr<char*> pcValue(new char*());
```

and used in the API like

```
SOME_API_FUNC(obj, prop,&*cValue);
```

My question is if this *cValue* is allocated with *malloc* internally inside the API then what happens since the *scoped_ptr* is using *delete*? Will *delete* clean up the memory properly? How to validate that the memory is cleaned up properly?

Comment: Any reason you use the C tag for a C++ question? They are different languages!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a smart pointer with a customizable deleter.

E.g. if you need to free that pointer with `free` instead of `delete` (the default deleter), try:

```
struct free_deleter {
     template <typename T> void operator()(T* p) const {
         ::free(p);
     }
};
template <typename T> using malloc_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, free_deleter>;
```

Now you can indeed assign malloced pointers and be fine:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> a(new char[100]); // ok, uses `delete[]`
std::unique_ptr<MyType> b(new MyType("param")); // ok, uses `delete`

malloc_ptr<char> legacy_buf(static_cast<char*>(::malloc(100))); //ok, uses `::free`
```